# ¿Como acortar una condición en php?

Tags: php, mysqli

Buenas tardes, he estado escribiendo este código que lo que hará sera mostrarme el producto dependiendo de que la talla final sea letra o números, en mi caso tengo los dos he estado haciendo esto pero imagínense hacer 50 comparaciones es mucho código y no quiero que sea tan largo ahí alguna manera de hacer estas comparaciones de una manera mas cortas

```
<?php
  $posteados ="SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY `id_producto` DESC LIMIT 8";
  $resPosteados=$mysqli->query($posteados);
    while ($fila = $resPosteados->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH) ){
        if(($fila['talla1'] == NULL) && ($fila['talla2'] == NULL) && ($fila['talla3'] == NULL)){
     echo  '<div class="product-item previews-3 large '.$fila['categoria'].'">';
     echo  '<div class="product-item-inside">';
     echo  '<div class="product-item-info">';
     echo  '<div class="product-item-photo">';
     echo  '<div class="product-item-gallery-main">';
     echo  '<a href="#">';
     echo  '<img class="product-image-photo" src="img/'.$fila['imagen_producto'].'" alt="">';
     echo  '</a>';
     echo  '<a href="quick-view.php?id='.$fila['id_producto'].'" title="Quick View" class="quick-view-link quick-view-btn">';
     echo  '<i class="icon icon-eye"></i>';
     echo  '<span>Vista rapida</span>';
     echo  '</a>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '<div class="product-item-actions">';
     echo  '<div class="share-button toBottom">';
     echo  '<span class="toggle"></span>';
     echo  '<ul class="social-list">';
     echo  '<li>';
     echo  '<a href="#" class="icon icon-twitter-logo twitter"></a>';
     echo  '</li>';
     echo  '<li>';
     echo  '<a href="#" class="icon icon-facebook-logo facebook"></a>';
     echo  '</li>';
     echo  '</ul>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '</div>';    
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '<div class="product-item-details">';
     echo  '<div class="product-item-name">';
     echo  '<a href="quick-view.php?id='.$fila['id_producto'].'" title="Quick View" class="quick-view-link ">'.$fila['titulo_producto'].'</a>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '<div class="product-item-description">Neque porro quisquam est, q incidunt ut labore</div>';
     echo  '<div class="price-box">';
     echo  '<span class="price-container">';
     echo  '<span class="price-wrapper">';
     echo  '<span class="price">Gs. '.$fila['precio_producto'].'</span>';
     echo  '</span>';
     echo  '</span>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '<div class="product-size watches">';
     echo  '<ul class="size-list">';
     if($fila['tallax']>0) echo  '<li><a href="#" ><span class="value">X</span></a></li>';
     if($fila['tallap']>0) echo  '<li><a href="#" ><span class="value">P</span></a></li>';
     if($fila['tallam']>0) echo  '<li><a href="#" ><span class="value">M</span></a></li>';
     if($fila['tallag']>0) echo  '<li><a href="#" ><span class="value">G</span></a></li>';
     if($fila['tallaxg']>0) echo  '<li><a href="#" ><span class="value">XG</span></a></li>';
     echo  '</ul>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '<button class="btn add-to-cart" data-product="'.$fila['id_producto'].'" onclick="agregar_carrito($(this))"  >';
     echo  '<i class="icon icon-cart"></i>';
     echo  '<span>Agregar a carrito</span>';
     echo  '</button>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo  '</div>';
 }}  ?>
```

esta parte es la que quiero evitar hacer 50 comparaciones
aclaro que los nombres de las columnas dentro de una tabla es la que definen el tamaño

```
if(($fila['talla1'] == NULL) && ($fila['talla2'] == NULL) && ($fila['talla3'] == NULL))
```

Comment: Cuales son todas las columnas que quieres comprobar, y qué objeto tiene hacer ese condicional?

Comment: en la tabla tengo una columna codigo_articulo lueog talla1 hasta talla 20 y luego tengo tallas como p xg g m y a la hora de mostrar me tendria que mostrar si el valor es null me muestra los talles en letra y si no es null me muestra los talles en numeros que varia dependiendo del articulo+

Comment: y puede pasar que un artículo tenga dos campos no nulos, o sea tenga dos tallas?

Comment: claro una remera tiene 5 tallas pero algunas prendas son talles en letras y otras talles en numeros

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) y comprobar si el `array`, en tu caso `$fila`, contiene el valor `null`, ejemplo:

```
// Simular tu contenido del array $fila
$fila = [
    'talla1' => 1,
    'talla2' => 2,
    'talla3' => null
  ];


// Comprobamos si el array contiene null
if (in_array(null, $fila)) {

    echo 'Hay uno o mas null en el array'; // Resultado

} else {

    echo 'todos tienen un valor';
}
```

[Sandbox del ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1f8113a733e85ca69aed847e592581942ea340b2)

Answer (score 0):

La idea seria insertar todo en un arreglo y luego recorrerlo

**ejemplo:**

```
$columnas=["talla1","tall2","talla3"...]
  for($i=0; $i<$columnas.length;$i++){
      if(($fila[$columnas[$i]] == NULL)){
      }
   }
```

Comment: Consulta en la variable $columnas tengo que poner los nombres de todas las columnas a comparar? esta genial

Comment: aun no lo he resuelto

Answer (score 0):

Podrías resolverlo de la siguiente forma:

- Crear un arreglo donde indicar los campos que deseas controlar (eg: `$talles`).
- Crear un contador para saber cuantos campos son igual a `NULL` (eg: `$contador`).
- Por cada producto, debes iterar el arreglo de talles y por cada valor en el arreglo, validar si en `$fila` es igual a `NULL`; de ser así, incrementamos el contador.
- Por último, si el contador es igual a la cantidad de campos en el arreglo, deberías continuar con la impresión de la ficha del producto.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$talles = array("talla1","tall2","talla3");
$tallesCantidad = count($talles);

$posteados ="SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY `id_producto` DESC LIMIT 8";
$resPosteados=$mysqli->query($posteados);
while ($fila = $resPosteados->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH) ){

    // Validación
    $contador = 0;
    foreach($talles as $talle) {
        if ($fila[$talle] === NULL) {
           $contador++;
        }
    }

    // Si todos los campos son `NULL`
    if ($contador === $tallesCantidad) {

        //..... aquí el resto del código

    } // if
 } // while
```

Comment: Te soy sincero, creo que la validación deberías hacerla en la consulta `SQL`, ya que se puede dar que:   
 - Supongamos tienes 10 (más de 8) productos.  
 - Solo los últimos 8 (`ORDER BY \`id_producto\` DESC LIMIT 8`) son los que tienen _talla1 o talla2 o etc._ distinto de `NULL`, es decir, no aparecerán productos en pantalla.  
Nunca estarías viendo REALMENTE los últimos 8 productos con talla1, talla2, etc. igual a `NULL`.